# Oracle Insert Φ symbol into table

Tags: oracle, insert, special-characters, symbols

I have problem with inserting **Φ** symbol to table...
I tried 
"insert into table (SYMBOL) values ('Φ');"

but result in table is sign '**?**'
Thanks!

Comment: What are your database and national character sets, what data type is the column, and what character set is your client using? Are you sure it's inserting a ?, not just showing you that when you query?

Comment: Try this page [GREEK CAPITAL LETTER PHI (U+03A6) Font Support](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=%CE%A6+-+GREEK+CAPITAL+LETTER+PHI+%28U%2B03A6%29) to check if your current font is able to display the character.

Answer (score 1):

First of all check whether you database is capable to store this character. You can do it by

```
SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER LIKE '%CHARACTERSET';
```

Character sets like `AL32UTF8`, `UTF8`, `AL16UTF16` or `WE8ISO8859P7` are capable to store Greek characters.

Character sets like `WE8ISO8859P1`, `US7ASCII` or `WE8MSWIN1252` are **not** capable to store Greek characters. In this case you cannot insert them into your database and your task ends here.

Another simple test is a SQL command like this:

```
SELECT 
    ASCIISTR(CAST(UNISTR('\03A6') AS VARCHAR2(4))) AS VARCHAR_SUPPORT, 
    ASCIISTR(CAST(UNISTR('\03A6') AS NVARCHAR2(4))) AS NVARCHAR_SUPPORT,
    CAST(UNISTR('\03A6') AS VARCHAR2(4)) AS VARCHAR_CHAR,
    CAST(UNISTR('\03A6') AS NVARCHAR2(4)) AS NVARCHAR_CHAR
FROM dual;

VARCHAR_SUPPORT NVARCHAR_SUPPORT VARCHAR_CHAR NVARCHAR_CHAR
--------------- ---------------- ------------ -------------
\00BF           \03A6            ¿            Φ            

1 row selected.
```

If your input code-point (in this example `U+03A6` which is the Unicode character `GREEK CAPITAL LETTER PHI`) is equal to result of `ASCIISTR` then your database can store the character. In my example I could insert "`Φ`" into a `NVARCHAR2` (or `NCHAR`) column but not into a `VARCHAR2` (or `CHAR`) column.

In case your database is capable to store Greek characters you can do always this command in SQL*Plus:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (UNISTR('\03A6'));
```

Depending on your requirements this can be a very tedious work. I think this method is an exceptional case only.

I don't recommend to enter a command like this directly in SQL*Plus:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES ('Φ');
```

In some cases it may work. So far I did not fully understand the relation between encodings of my PC and the encoding of SQL*Plus.

A more secure way is to write such SQL-Statement into a `.sql`-file and save it.
In order to run it, set your `NLS_LANG` environment variable according to the charaterset of this file. For example, when you saved it as `UTF-8` then run (for Windows)

```
c:\>set NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8

c:\>sqlplus user/pwd@DB @My_Inserts.sql
```

If your `.sql`-file is saved as `ANSI`, then on a "Western PC" it would be this:

```
c:\>set NLS_LANG=.WE8MSWIN1252

c:\>sqlplus user/pwd@DB @My_Inserts.sql
```

`ANSI` Encoding actually means "current local encoding". If you don't your local codepage you can interrogate it with this command:

```
C:\>reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage /v ACP

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage
    ACP    REG_SZ    1252

C:\>
```